# Seeking a proof of the unsolvability of the Entscheidungsproblem

Tags: first-order-logic

In Joel W. Robbin's "Mathematical logic, a first course" there are five exercises (11 to 15, pp 169 & 170) the solutions to which constitute a proof of the unsolvability of the Entscheidungsproblem.  If anyone knows if the solutions are to be found anywhere I'll be pleased to be told where.  No, it's not homework!